# Como acomodar los campos de un formulario con bootstrap?

Tags: java, html, bootstrap, jsp

Quiero acomodar campos de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo los siguientes **campos**, y solo se muestran los `combos` 1 y 3, pero no se como acomodar de forma que salgan los combos 2 y 4 como en la imagen
como le pudo hacer?

y de igual manera no se como acomodar los campos de arriba, que en una sola *fila* salgan las `etiquetas` y debajo de ellas los campos
Ojala puedan apoyarme, gracias

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>
<form class="form horizontal">
<div class="panel-info">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2 control-label">COMBO1</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
</div>
<br></br>
<label class="col-lg-2 control-label">COMBO3</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: en la imgen veo un grupo en la parte superior y otro en la inferior, caual quieres acomodar ?

Comment: La dos,bueno más la inferior, la de los combos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con el sistema de grillas de boostrap lo puedes hacer asi:

```
 <form class="form horizontal">
  <div class="panel-info">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">COMBO1</label>
            <select class="col-md-8 form-control">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>1</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <br></br>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">COMBO2</label>
            <select class="col-md-8 form-control">
              <option>2</option>
              <option>2</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">COMBO3</label>
            <select class="col-md-8 form-control">
              <option>3</option>
              <option>3</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <br></br>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">COMBO4</label>
            <select class="col-md-8 form-control">
              <option>4</option>
              <option>4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**NOTA:** en caso de que el contenedor padre sea muy pequeño entonces te lo pondra el `label` encima del `select`, en ese caso puedes prescindir del `label` poniendole un `option` por defecto, o asignale espacio al `label` y al `select`.

espero te sirva, me cuentas!

Comment: Ya lo probé y si pone el label encima del select,  mencionas que poniéndole espacio al label y select? Espacio como?

Comment: perame edito la respuesta, auque ello siempre dependera del tamaño de label y del contenido del combo

Comment: Listo @Root93 ya quedo, debes tener en cuenta que los espacio asignados siempre depende del contenero padre, los hijos de ahi en adelante pueden tomar las grillas que necesiten sin sobrepasar el limite del padre. me cuentas!

Comment: Ya lo probé y lo sigue mostrando encima, sólo que cambio de posición, muestra el label  en el centro

Comment: Ya quedó,lo que hice fue asignarle un tamaño a los combos y ya los muestra como quiero, gracias!!

Comment: De nada bro, siempre es un placer ayudar ReNiceCode...

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo estas usando Bootstrap para adaptar tu diseño, no identifico cual es la versión que estas usando, dejo un ejemplo de acuerdo a tu imagen con Bootstrap 4, espero te pueda servir de guía para que lo adaptes a tus necesidades.

**Para que se vea el efecto, hay que visualizarlo en pantalla completa**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>--</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <label for="">Campo 1</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <label for="">Campo 2</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <label for="">Campo 3</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-2" for="Combo1">Combo 1</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <label class="col-sm-2" for="Combo2">Combo 2</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-2" for="Combo3">Combo 3</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <label class="col-sm-2" for="Combo4">Combo 4</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </form>

    <!-- JQuery , Bootstrap.js -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que para lo que quieres uses `display:flex;`aqui esta la  [documentacion](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) y un poco de **css** mira este ejemplo

```css
.form-group{

display:flex;
}


label{
margin:10px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>
<form class="form horizontal">
<div class="panel-info">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="form-group " >
<label class="col-lg-2 control-label ml-3">COMBO1
<div class="col-lg-10">
<select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
</div>
</label>

<label class="col-lg-2 control-label ml-3">COMBO3
<div class="col-lg-10">
<select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
</div>
</label>

<label class="col-lg-2 control-label ml-3">COMBO3
<div class="col-lg-10">
<select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
</div>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A ver si esto te puede servir...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">  
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       
         <form class="col-12">
          <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-6 my-1">
              <label class="mr-sm-2"
                     for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Combo 1</label>
              <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" 
                      id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                <option selected>Combo 1...</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
              </select>                            
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-1">
              <label class="mr-sm-2"
                     for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Combo 2</label>
              <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" 
                      id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                <option selected>Combo 2...</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
              </select>                            
            </div>
           </div>
           
         <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-6 my-1">
              <label class="mr-sm-2"
                     for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Combo 3</label>
              <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" 
                      id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                <option selected>Combo 3...</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
              </select>                            
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-1">
              <label class="mr-sm-2"
                     for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Combo 4</label>
              <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" 
                      id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                <option selected>Combo 4..</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
              </select>                            
            </div>
           </div>                      
        </form> 
    </div>
  </div>
```